# How to add options to an HTML Table using Apps Script?

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I was wondering how I could add these options to an HTML table within Apps Script Editor.

Here's the script:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate();
}

/* PROCESS FORM */
function processForm(formObject) {
  var result = "";
  if (formObject.searchtext) {//Execute if form passes search text
    result = search(formObject.searchtext);
  }
  return result;
}

//SEARCH FOR MATCHED CONTENTS 

function search(searchtext) {
  //const searchtext = 'test@email.com'
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var spreadsheetId = ss.getId();
  var dataRage = 'Approval Tracker!A2:J';
  var data = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, dataRage).values;
  var ar = [];

  data.forEach(function (f) {
    if (f[9] == searchtext) {
      ar.push([f[3], f[4], f[5], f[6], f[2]]);
    }
  });
  return ar;
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-xrRywqdh3PHs8keKZN+8zzc5TX0GRTLCcmivcbNJWm2rs5C8PRhcEn3czEjhAO9o" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>

  <!--##JAVASCRIPT FUNCTIONS ---------------------------------------------------- -->
  <script>
    //PREVENT FORMS FROM SUBMITTING / PREVENT DEFAULT BEHAVIOUR
          function preventFormSubmit() {
            var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
            for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
              forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
              event.preventDefault();
              });
            }
          }
          window.addEventListener("load", preventFormSubmit, true); 
              
           
          //HANDLE FORM SUBMISSION
          function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createTable).processForm(formObject);
            //document.getElementById("search-form").reset();
          }
         
          //CREATE THE DATA TABLE
          function createTable(dataArray) {
            if(dataArray && dataArray !== undefined && dataArray.length != 0){
              var result = "<table class='table table-sm table-striped' id='dtable' style='font-size:0.8em'>"+
                           "<thead style='white-space: nowrap'>"+
                             "<tr>"+                               //Change table headings to match witht he Google Sheet
                              "<th scope='col'>Date Assigned</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>Item</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>Link To File</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>Notes</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>Approval Status</th>"+
                              "<td><select name='D1'>" +
                                                            "<option value='volvo'>Volvo</option>" +
                                                            "<option value='saab'>Saab</option>" +
                                                            "<option value='mercedes'>Mercedes</option>" +
                                                            "<option value='audi'>Audi</option>" +
                                                            "</select>"+
                              "</td>" +
                              "</tr>" +
                              "</thead>";
              for(var i=0; i<dataArray.length; i++) {
                  result += "<tr>";
                  for(var j=0; j<dataArray[i].length; j++){
                      result += "<td>"+dataArray[i][j]+"</td>";
                  }
                  result += "</tr>";
              }
              result += "</table>";
              var div = document.getElementById('search-results');
              div.innerHTML = result;
            }else{
              var div = document.getElementById('search-results');
              //div.empty()
              div.innerHTML = "Data not found!";
            }
          }
  </script>
  <!--##JAVASCRIPT FUNCTIONS ~ END ---------------------------------------------------- -->

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <br>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">

        <!-- ## SEARCH FORM ------------------------------------------------ -->
        <form id="search-form" class="form-inline" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
          <div class="form-group mb-2">
            <label for="searchtext">Enter your email</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchtext" name="searchtext" placeholder="Enter your email">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Search</button>
        </form>
        <!-- ## SEARCH FORM ~ END ------------------------------------------- -->

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">

        <!-- ## TABLE OF SEARCH RESULTS ------------------------------------------------ -->
        <div id="search-results" class="table-responsive">
          <!-- The Data Table is inserted here by JavaScript -->
        </div>
        <!-- ## TABLE OF SEARCH RESULTS ~ END ------------------------------------------------ -->

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[This is the file's link:](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxNn4I2tZRXlDKrBcyp8S6EciMAdug3FvRFoIIjLHky5z74Qa0kdzkRFGfMeOjFODPV/exec)

[This is the Web App URL](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxNn4I2tZRXlDKrBcyp8S6EciMAdug3FvRFoIIjLHky5z74Qa0kdzkRFGfMeOjFODPV/exec)

It's now appending one koption list to the header.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `I was wondering how I could add these options to an HTML table within Apps Script Editor.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your question?

Comment: Hi, @Tanaike! Thanks for replying! I've added the expected HTML - especially with the last column giving the users options. Thanks for your attention and time!

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If your showing script is not your current script for replicating your issue, my proposed modification might not be able to be used. At that time, can you provide your whole script for replicating your current issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `I've tried it above but the page is empty.`, if your are using your showing script, I think that your script is incomplete. So, please modify as follows and test it again.

#### From:

```
  "<option value='audi'>Audi</option>" +
  "</select></td>
"</tr>" +
  "</thead>";
```

#### To:

```
"<option value='audi'>Audi</option>" +
"</select></td></tr></thead>";
```

Comment: Appreciate your will and patience! I have updated the question with the file with dummy data and link. Thank you!

Comment: @santosOnit Thank you for replying. About `I have updated the question with the file with dummy data and link.`, I think that it is a new question. Your 1st question was resolved. And, you want to change your 1st question to a new question. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Thank YOU! You're totally right. I've just created a new question!

Comment: @santosOnit Thank you for replying. I would like to check your new question.

Comment: Appreciate that very much, as usual! https://stackoverflow.com/q/72253401/11832197