# How to populate one of the HTML Table columns with pre-set options using Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I am trying to get this table to display the options for each of the table rows, but I can't quite get it:

I suppose I'd set it in the seconf `for loop`, but I'm new to `html` and can't move forward.

```
<script>
    //PREVENT FORMS FROM SUBMITTING / PREVENT DEFAULT BEHAVIOUR
          function preventFormSubmit() {
            var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
            for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
              forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
              event.preventDefault();
              });
            }
          }
          window.addEventListener("load", preventFormSubmit, true); 
              
           
          //HANDLE FORM SUBMISSION
          function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createTable).processForm(formObject);
            //document.getElementById("search-form").reset();
          }
         
          //CREATE THE DATA TABLE
          function createTable(dataArray) {
            if(dataArray && dataArray !== undefined && dataArray.length != 0){
              var result = "<table class='table table-sm table-striped' id='dtable' style='font-size:0.8em'>"+
                           "<thead style='white-space: nowrap'>"+
                             "<tr>"+                               //Change table headings to match witht he Google Sheet
                              "<th scope='col'>Client</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>Name</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>Date</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>Approval</th>"+
                            "</tr>"+
                          "</thead>";
              for(var i=0; i<dataArray.length; i++) {
                  result += "<tr>";
                  for(var j=0; j<dataArray[i].length; j++){
                      result += "<td>"+dataArray[i][j]+"</td>";
                  }
                  result += "</tr>";
              }
              result += "</table>";
              var div = document.getElementById('search-results');
              div.innerHTML = result;
            }else{
              var div = document.getElementById('search-results');
              //div.empty()
              div.innerHTML = "Data not found!";
            }
          }
  </script>
```

[This is the file's](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BDTfDfVimE6X7hXFziKX5fgFzG3IiATvf3V6MBoAke8/edit?usp=sharing)

[This is the Web App URL](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxNn4I2tZRXlDKrBcyp8S6EciMAdug3FvRFoIIjLHky5z74Qa0kdzkRFGfMeOjFODPV/exec)

Here's the current result:
[image]

Comment: About `Here's the current result:`, can I ask you about your expected result?

Comment: Sure, @Tanaike! Sorry about that. Instead of having it show in the header only, each row should give the users the dropdown list of options. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your goal, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to put the dropdown list in the column "Approval".

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Please modify the function `createTable` as follows.

```js
function createTable(dataArray) {
  if (dataArray && dataArray !== undefined && dataArray.length != 0) {
    var option = "<select name='D1'>" +
      "<option value='volvo'>Volvo</option>" +
      "<option value='saab'>Saab</option>" +
      "<option value='mercedes'>Mercedes</option>" +
      "<option value='audi'>Audi</option>" +
      "</select>";
    var result = "<table class='table table-sm table-striped' id='dtable' style='font-size:0.8em'>" +
      "<thead style='white-space: nowrap'>" +
      "<tr>" +                               //Change table headings to match witht he Google Sheet
      "<th scope='col'>Client</th>" +
      "<th scope='col'>Name</th>" +
      "<th scope='col'>Date</th>" +
      "<th scope='col'>Approval</th>" +
      "<td>" +
      "</td>" +
      "</tr>" +
      "</thead>";
    for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
      result += "<tr>";
      for (var j = 0; j < dataArray[i].length; j++) {
        result += "<td>" + dataArray[i][j] + "</td>";
      }
      result += "<td>" + option + "</td>";
      result += "</tr>";
    }
    result += "</table>";
    var div = document.getElementById('search-results');
    div.innerHTML = result;
  } else {
    var div = document.getElementById('search-results');
    //div.empty()
    div.innerHTML = "Data not found!";
  }
}
```

- `option` is from your previous question. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72252525/7108653)

Comment: @santosOnit Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.